# Issue when working with ArrayWritables

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I'm a beginner in Hadoop and was working with the *ArrayWritables* in Hadoop map-reduce.

And this is the **Mapper** code I'm using :-

```
public class Base_Mapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    String currLine[] = new String[1000];
    Text K = new Text();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString();
        currLine = line.split("");
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < currLine.length; i++) {
            String currToken = currLine[i];
            count++;
            K.set(currToken);
            context.write(K, new IntWritable(count));
        }

    }
}
```

**Reducer :-**

```
public class Base_Reducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable,Text, IntArrayWritable> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        IntArrayWritable finalArray = new IntArrayWritable();
        IntWritable[] arr = new IntWritable[1000];
        for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++)
            arr[i] = new IntWritable(0);
        int redCount = 0;
        for (IntWritable val : values) {
            int thisValue = val.get();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 150; i++) {
                if (thisValue == i)
                    arr[i - 1] = new IntWritable(redCount++);
            }
        }
        finalArray.set(arr);
        context.write(key, finalArray);
    }

}
```

I'm using ***IntArrayWritable*** as subclass of ***ArrayWritable*** as shown below :-

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.ArrayWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;

public class IntArrayWritable extends ArrayWritable {
    public IntArrayWritable() {
        super(IntWritable.class);
    }

    public IntArrayWritable(IntWritable[] values) {
        super(IntWritable.class, values);
    }
}
```

My Intended output of the Job was some set of Bases as key(which is correct) and an array of *IntWritables* as value. 
But I'm getting the output as:-

```
    com.feathersoft.Base.IntArrayWritable@30374534
A   com.feathersoft.Base.IntArrayWritable@7ca071a6
C   com.feathersoft.Base.IntArrayWritable@9858936
G   com.feathersoft.Base.IntArrayWritable@1df33d1c
N   com.feathersoft.Base.IntArrayWritable@4c3108a0
T   com.feathersoft.Base.IntArrayWritable@272d6774
```

What are all changes I have to make inorder to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override default behavior of `toString()` method in your `IntArrayWritable` implementation.

Please try this:

```java
import org.apache.hadoop.io.ArrayWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;

public class IntArrayWritable extends ArrayWritable {
    public IntArrayWritable() {
        super(IntWritable.class);
    }

    public IntArrayWritable(IntWritable[] values) {
        super(IntWritable.class, values);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("[");

        for (String s : super.toStrings())
        {
            sb.append(s).append(" ");
        }

        sb.append("]")
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

If you liked this answer please mark it as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: I've tried out this code. But it gives me an exception in the reduce phase of the job. This is the stack-trace of the error. Stacktrace :::Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.hadoop.io.ArrayWritable.toStrings(ArrayWritable.java:74)
 at com.feathersoft.Base.IntArrayWritable.toString(IntArrayWritable.java:18)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat$LineRecordWriter.writeObject(TextOutputFormat.java:85)

Comment: Do i need to change any of the reducer part of it .? I need to get the output as array of IntWritables. Please help me !

Comment: You can't send `null` values to the IntArrayWritable. In your reducer you are allocation array for 1000 values `IntWritable[] arr = new IntWritable[1000];`, but you use only 150 of them and rest of the are `null`.